# From there to Berlin, dorther von or dorther nach?

Tags: adverb

This is an example of using the adverb *dorther* from Mastering German Vocabulary:

> English: how far is it from there to Berlin?
>
> German: wie weit ist es dorther von Berlin?

Is this correct?  Why is it **von** and not **nach**?

[image: Grammar]

Comment: If you want to use the available pieces, you could say: "Wie weit ist Berlin von dorther." Still, this sentence sounds strange.

Comment: The way to use "dorther" that I would recommend to most learners is to not use it at all.

Comment: "dorthin" would make more sense. but then it would no longer mean the same as the english original. this is either archaic or plain wrong

Comment: @CarstenS why? Newspapers use it so it's obviosuly not outdated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"dorther" is in theory a correct german word, but nobody uses it in this context (anymore). The correct sentence would be:

> Wie weit ist es von dorther nach Berlin?

However, much more common would be:

> Wie weit ist es von dort nach Berlin?

"von dort" = "from there"
"nach Berlin" = "to Berlin"

Answer (score -2):

it is correct because "nach" indicates a direction/ a movement forward (-->) 
whereas in this case there is no idea of movement hence: "von".

"Berlin liegt X km von dorther entfernt." --> entfernt kann nicht wegfallen

Comment: Welcome to German.Stackexchange! Unfortunately your first answer seems to be wrong and instead of writing comments with critique, people decided to go the easy way and downvote your answer.

Comment: The original sentence: "how far is it from there to Berlin?" does have movement in it, moving from "there" to "Berlin". How do you explain that?